# Coverage regex in Gitlab Auto Devops for scoverage-gradle plugin

Tags: scala, gradle, akka, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am testing Auto DevOps from Gitlab and I created an small project using Scala, Akka and Gradle. I have scoverage-plugin configured in my `build.gradle`.

I can not get the regex to show coverage badge and I can not find it. I tested with `Coverage was \[\d+.\d+\%\]` like sbt-scala project, but it does not work.

Does anybody know what is the regex?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
Coverage was \[(\d+.\d+)\%\]
```

Note the parenthesis.